# Calculate function in matlab

Tags: matlab, function-handle

is there any way to calculate a function in matlab using toolbox? for example I have this function: f(x,y)=x^2+y^2, I want to set x=2 and y=2 and function take back 8. How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is `function handle`. Feel free to add  `MATLAB` into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use anonymous functions, for example:

```
f=@(x,y)x.^2+y.^2;
```

or just write a file for example `abc.m` that has this code:

```
 function f=abc(x,y)
 f= x.^2+y.^2;
```

then abc(2,2) will return the answer if the function file is at the path.

Comment: This is good, takes care of any sized arrays, not just scalars.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html):

```
>> f = @(x,y) x^2+y^2;
>> f(2,2)

ans =

     8
```